In an air-conditioned house, is the dryer more energy-efficient than hang-drying?
When the air conditioning is running, which consumes the least energy: using the dryer (which sends the humidity outside) or indoor air-drying (which requires the air conditioner to remove the humidity)?
(Obviously it would be more efficient to hang the clothes outside, but that is not always an option.)

That's easy.
When indoor air-drying, when the moisture in the clothes evaporates, it absorbs heat. So it makes your house cooler.
Then when the air conditioning evaporator coil encounters the evaporated moisture, the moisture releases the heat it has absorbed.
The two effects (evaporating moisture absorbing heat and condensing moisture releasing heat) cancel each other out exactly. No net energy lost due to air-drying.
If the air conditioner is of the type that it evaporates the condensed moisture in the condenser coil again, then it could even help energy efficiency, since the re-evaporating moisture would cool the condenser coil in a better manner then, meaning the condenser coil temperature just dropped, which has a tendency to improve air conditioner efficiency.
However, things may change in a heated house during the heating season. Then the air-drying absorbs heat, making the house cooler. There's no place inside the house where the heat would be released due to condensing moisture. Therefore, the heating system of the house has to work harder, consuming more energy.
A very energy efficient (heat pump based) clothes dryer could very well be more economical than air-drying during the heating season, if you ignore the massive purchase and maintenance costs of a heat pump based clothes dryer (but on the other hand, air-drying requires lots of surface area of the house, so that could make air-drying even more expensive).
However, in an air conditioned house, air-drying is always more energy-efficient than a separate clothes dryer, since air-drying consumes no net energy then, whereas a clothes dryer consumes extra energy.
